# UWP Project: how to attach a drop shadow (Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.AttachedShadowBase) to a UIElement in CODE

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

Right, I have been using the old approach of doing DropShadows (`ElementCompositionPreview`...) in code.

That approach is marked DEPRECATED.

Using the new `AttachedDropShadow` is fine in XAML, but what about in C# code? I do not see any documentation on how to use this helper in straight C#. I want to attach it to a `UIElement`.

Any help?

Comment: From the [XAML markup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/attachedshadows#example), you can see that Effects.Shadow is an attached property, so you use [Effects.SetShadow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.effects.setshadow#microsoft-toolkit-uwp-ui-effects-setshadow(windows-ui-xaml-frameworkelement-microsoft-toolkit-uwp-ui-attachedshadowbase)).

Comment: Cool, will try it out and report back. Thx

Comment: Right, tried this:

                         shadow = new Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.AttachedDropShadow()
                        {
                            Opacity = 0.5f,
                            BlurRadius = 20,
                            Offset = new Vector3(10,10,10).ToString(),
                            Color = Colors.Black
                        };
                        Effects.SetShadow(e, shadow); 

Is not working...

Comment: Oh, I should mention that I position FrameworkElements on a Canvas. The sprite-based drop shadow of yore works...

Comment: Forgot to mention that that entire FrameworkElement has an attached TransformGroup as well...

Comment: Does it work from markup? The original question was "What is the C# version of this markup?" not "How do I get this to show the shadow I want?" I assumed the markup worked and you just wanted to translate it into C#.

Comment: Works in the surrounding Markup, cannot test is easily in the canvas itself... could that be the issue? Canvas seems a bit... odd.

Comment: If you want to perfectly mimic what happens in markup, use `element.SetValue(Effects.ShadowProperty, shadow)`. By tradition, each attached property `C.P` has [a convenience method](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/5d5d86fd7d7ad75fa989683a95b6835aeb4efdc4/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI/Shadows/Effects.cs#L31) called `C.SetP(element, value)` that does `element.SetValue(C.PProperty, value)`.